# Rudin Theorem 2.7

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

Theorem 2.7 in Rudin's Real and Complex analysis

**Theorem** Suppose $U$ is open in a locally compact Hausdorff space X, $K \subset U$, and $K$ is compact. Then there is an open set $V$ with compact closure such that $K \subset V \subset \text{cl}(V) \subset U$.

**Proof** Since every point of K has a neighbourhood with compact closure, and since $K$ is covered by the union of finitely many of these neighbourhoods, $K$ lies in an open set $G$ with compact closure. If $U=X$ ,take $V=G$.
Otherwise, let $C$ be the complement of $U$. Theorem 2.5 shows that to each $p\in C$ there corresponds an open set $W_p$ such that $K \subset W_p$ and $p\notin \text{cl}(W_p)$ ...

**Theorem 2.5** Suppose X is a Hausdorff space , $K \subset X$, $K$ is compact, and $p \in K^c$. Then there are open sets $U$ and $W$ such that $p\in U$, $K \subset W$ and $U \cap W=\emptyset$.

**Question**: I understand that by applying 2.5 to $K \subset U (p\in C=U^c \subset K^c)$ we get $W_p $ and $U_p$ such that $K\subset W_p$ and $p\in U_p$, $W_p \cap U_p=\emptyset \Rightarrow p\notin W_p$, but how do we know for sure that $p\notin \text{cl}(W_p)$?

Comment: If $p$ were in the closure of $W_p$, then every neighborhood of $p$, in particular $U_p$, would have to meet $W_p$.