# Proof that there exist an open set with compact closure explanation

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

I'm reading Rudins "Complex Analysis". There's a theorem that goes like this.

**Theorem**: Let $U$ be open, in a locally compact Hausdorff space. Let $K\subset U$ and $K$ be compact. Then there exist an open set $V$ such that
$$K\subset V\subset \overline{V}\subset U $$
**Proof**:

Because every point of $K$ has a neighbourhood that's closure is compact, and we can cover $K$ with finite amount of such neighbourhoods, then there exist a set $G$, that has a compact closure, and is a subset of $K$. If $U=X$ then we can take $V=G$.

If not, define $C$ as the complement of $U$. From theorem $2.5$, for every point $p\in C$, there exist an open set $W_p$, such that $K\subset W_p$, and $p\notin\overline{W_p}$.

And the proof goes on.

**Theorem $2.5$**: Suppose that $X$ is a Hausdorff space, $K\subset X$ is a compact set, and $p\in K^c$. Then there exist open sets $U$ and $W$, such that $p\in U$, $K\subset W$, and $U \cap W = \emptyset$.

My question is, how we can use this theorem in the proof, so that we can state the existence of such sets $W_p$. Mainly, where does $p\notin\overline{W_p}$ come from. Thank you.

Another question that might help me. If $U$ and $V$ are open, $U\cap V=\emptyset$ holds, does $\overline{U}\cap V=\emptyset$?

I've found a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/913310/rudin-theorem-2-7?rq=1). In the comments, Andreas says that if $p$ was in closure of $W_p$, then every neighbourhood of $p$ would have to meet $W_p$. Why is that?

Comment: Re: "Another  question" : If $V$ is open then its complement is $V^c$ is closed and disjoint from $V $. So if $ V $  is open and is disjoint from $U$ then $V\cap \overline U\subset  V \cap \overline V^c=$ $V \cap V^c=\emptyset.$... Another way to see this is that if $V$ is open and $U\cap V= \emptyset,$ then every $p\in V $ has a  nbhd (namely, $V $ ) that's disjoint from $U,$ so  $p\not \in \overline U.$

Comment: The theorem, with  $\overline V$  compact,  directly:   (1). In a Hausdorff space if $C$ is compact and $p\not\in C$ than $p, C$ are completely separated. (2). If $D$ is open and $ \overline D$ is compact then $\partial D= \overline D$ \ $ D$ is compact. (3). We use (1) and (2) to prove that a compact $T_2$ space is regular..... Then  for each $p \in K$ let $V_p, U_p$  be open  sets containing $p$ such that $\overline V_p$ is compact and $\overline U_p\subset  U. $ Now  $A=\{V_p\cap U_p: p\in K\}$ is an open cover of $K.$  Let $B$ be a finite sub-cover of $A$  and let $V=\cup B.$

Comment: ERRATUM: In my previous comment , (3) should say  that a LOCALLY compact $T_2$ space is regular. I ran out of editing time .

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Thank you! I get it now.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Hausdorff condition. For each $a\in K$ there are disjoint
open neighbourhoods $U_a$ and $V_a$ of $p$ and $a$ respectively.
Finitely many of the $V_a$ will cover $K$; let $W$ be their union,
and $U$ the intersection of the corresponding $U_a$.

Comment: Yes, that's how the proof of **Theorem $2.5$** is stated. My question is how to use this theorem

Comment: The point is that $U$ and $W$ are **disjoint**.

Comment: $U$ and $W$ are disjoint, does that imply that, for example, $\overline{U}$ and $W$ are disjoint?

Comment: $W$ is **open**