# Explanation of specific parts of Urysohn's Lemma proof

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, proof-explanation

[image]
[image]

While reading and trying to understand the proof I got stuck in some parts of the proof.

- Why can we take all the $V_{r_i}$ in such manner? Shall we say first w.l.o.g ?:

  Suppose $n\ge2$ and $V_{r_1},...,V_{r_n}$ have been chosen in such a manner that $r_i<r_j$ implies $\overline V_{r_j}\subset V_{r_i}$.
- How can we know that $\overline V_j$ are all compact sets? We need this hypothesis so that Theorem [2.7](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/913310/rudin-theorem-2-7) can be applied.
- Why is it enought to mention that $f$ is lower-semicontinuous and $g$ is upper-semicontinuous to have continuity of $f$?
- The author wrote it's clear that $f$ has it's support in $\overline V_0$.

Actually we need the support to be in $V$; by (2) it's done.

Here is how I proved, please verify.

Let's see that $\{x:f(x)\neq 0\}\subset V_0$ (we then take closures on both sides).

Let $x\in\{x:f(x)\neq 0\}$ and let´s see that $x\in V_0.$

We have $f(x)\neq 0$.

By definition $f=\sup_r f_r.$ Thus $\sup_r f_r\neq 0$.

Now we must have $f_r=r$ if $x\in V_r$ otherwise $f_r=0,\sup_r f_r=0=f$, contradiction.

If $x\in V_r,f_r=r$.

We have $r>0,$ thus $\overline V_r\subset V_0.$ Thus $x\in V_0$

Hence
$\{x:f(x)\neq 0\}\subset V_0$. Taking closures, we have the result.

Comment: may I know why the downvote?

Comment: In your first question, I think you're getting confused by the direction of the implication. The claim that $f(x) = 1$ if $x \in K$ means that, for every $x \in K$, $f(x) = 1$. It does not mean that, for every $x$ with $f(x) = 1$, $x \in K$ -- that claim, which isn't true, would be expressed as *``$f(x) = 1$ only if $x \in K$''.

Comment: @K.MacDonald got it. If $x\in K$ then $x\in V_1$ by (2). By (4), $f_r(x)=1$. Therefore $f=1$ since $sup(1)=1$. Am I right?

Comment: @AaronMartinez If you don't get a good answer in the next couple of days I can write one up (just lightly browsing the question feed at the moment... no time now I am afraid). I recall having to fight for every inch reading through Rudin myself a while back ;)

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen :D thank you so much for your attention. And don't worry even after the bounty you could post it ;) hahaha..  well yeah this Rudin and his pedantic proofs. Anyway Mirko posted an answer haven't read it yet though, It will cost me a headhache to read it but it'll woth it

Comment: @AaronMartinez No bounty doesn't bother me. I rarely post answers because I hate the reputation system anyway :) Not a fan of gamification... I only accept it sometimes so I can in turn put bounties on questions that deserve them. Read Mirko's answer first and add an update to your question with any remain concerns you have and I'll get to them. As for reading Rudin? It's hard and Rudin is almost never the best source on any topic in his book. Why keep it around then? Reference material. You'll have a far easier time reading a better text, e.g. Royden, Stein, etc.

Comment: ... that being said, I first learned from Rudin, so some suggestions I would give is take it slowly, make sure you understand where stuff is coming from, try to read it with someone else if possible, use the internet as much as you can, supplant it with other reading material (preferably more intro level stuff), and understand that some parts will require mathematical maturity to appreciate that comes with time - you might not get everything on a first try, and that is alright.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Thanks again Brevan, you´re nice person :)

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen  I have a question regarding the semicontinuity of $f$. I tried to prove that $f$ is lower semicontinuous. Here is the proof. We need to show that $\displaystyle\lim_{x→x0}\inf f(x)≥f(x_0).$ Let $x_0∈X.$ Case 1: consider $x_0∈V_r$. Thus $f_r(x_0)=r$ and $f=\sup_r f_r=\sup_r f_r(x_0)=\sup_rr=r.$ This implies $\displaystyle\lim_{x→x_0}\inf f(x)=\lim_{x→x0}\inf_r=r=f(x_0).$ Case 2: consider $x_0∉V_r$. Thus $f_r(x_0)=0.$ This implies $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to x_0}\inf f=0≥f(x_0)=0.$ though I don't know if it's correct.

Comment: @AaronMartinez You are overcomplicating things. Look at the comments after Definition 2.8 like Rudin says. You'll see that characteristic functions of open sets are lower semicontinuous. Now notice $f = r\cdot \chi(V_r)$, where $\chi(V_r)$ is the characteristic function of the open set $V_r$. A nearly identical observation shows $g$ is upper semicontinuous. (It should hopefully be clear that scaling a semicontinuous function leaves it semicontinuous. Consider the definition for a moment if this is not clear)

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen  right  that result helps. I can see that $f$ is lower semicontinuous. The function $g$ would be $g=1\cdot\chi(\overline V_s)+s\chi(\overline V_s^c)$ ? but then would be lower semicontinuous or upper semicontinuous?

Comment: @AaronMartinez I would go from definition with $g$ using the *idea* for how to prove it for indicators. Recall our function is upper semicontinuous if $\{x : g(x) < \alpha \}$ is open for all real $\alpha$. In this case, if $\alpha > 1$ we get the whole space, if $s < \alpha \le 1$ we get $(\bar{V}_s)^c$ and if $\alpha \le s$ we get the empty set. Each of these three possibilities yields an open set, so $g$ is upper semicontinuous

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen the definition of $g$ in your proof is the one that I wrote $g=1\cdot\chi(\overline V_s)+s\chi(\overline V_s^c)$?

Comment: @AaronMartinez Not sure what you are saying. It is the definition you are using and the one Rudin is using; they are both the same thing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94894/discussion-between-aaron-martinez-and-brevan-ellefsen).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you study Rudin's proof of Urysohn’s Lemma and want to describe what it is doing at the start, you might come up with

> The proof begins by invoking Theorem 2.7 a countably infinite number of times to construct a sequence of open sets, while 'tracking' the rational number 'assignments' using an 'interpolation' technique to keep the chain of open sets 'sorted'.

The proof is also implicitly using the [Axiom of dependent choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_dependent_choice), $\mathsf {DC}$, to construct this sequence of open sets. The OP should be aware that the construction of the chain of open sets

$$\tag 1 V_1 \subset \dots \subset V_\alpha \subset \dots \subset V_\beta \subset \dots \subset V_0 \text{ where } \alpha,\beta \in \{r_n\}  \text{ and } \alpha \gt \beta $$

is accomplished by creating a function(sequence) using recursion/[choice.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_choice) If the chain has length $n$, you can increase the length by $1$ while keeping that rational number 'link-up' in place. Recursion lets you finish up with a countable family $(V_n)_{n\ge0}$, and after 'sorting', you have a two-sided chain as expressed by $\text{(1)}$.

Usually (almost always?) when defining a sequence using recursion the index set consists of the natural numbers. But in Rudin's recursion step, we find

> Suppose $n \ge 2$ and $V_{r_1}, V_{r_2}, \dots, V_{r_n}$  have been chosen in such a manner that...

It might be helpful (more rigorous?) to think of each of the $V \text{ sets }$ as having two subscripts, the rational number as well as the $n$ corresponding to its recursive construction.

The recursion also starts off with an 'initialized state' for the first two terms of the sequence, $V_{r_1} = V_0$ and $V_{r_2} = V_1$. Also, the way the recursion works, all the prior terms of the sequence are inputs to form the next 'interpolation' term (no Fibonacci here!). The final output structure of the recursion, the infinite chain $\text{(1)}$ with some concomitant properties, is all that is needed to create the desired continuous function.

It is helpful to imagine rational numbers like $\frac{1}{2}$,$\frac{1}{4}$,$\frac{3}{4}$, etc. 'feeding the recursion' and creating the next term of the sequence as well as the chain relation in $\text{(1)}$.

To picture how the proof creates the continuous function $f$, try to 'see it over' the $\text{(1)-chain expression}$ as a decreasing function that starts at $1$ over $V_1$ and goes to $0$ over $V_0$. The picture will 'look like' an increasing continuous function

$\quad g: [0,1] \text{ (reverse the (1)-chain)} \to [0,1]$.

But of course the topological space $X$ can be finite in which case this 'picture' is not accurate (see example in next section).

In the proof you will see the use of the $\text{supremum }$ function, and it is how you can define the desired function $f$ while guaranteeing that is continuous.

---

Example 1: Let $X =\{0,1\}$ be the discreet topological space containing $2$ points. Let $K = \{1\}$ and $V = X$. Using the argument found in Rudin's proof of Urysohn's Lemma, depending on the choices you make, exactly two continuous function can be created

$\quad {\chi}_K \text{ and } {\chi}_X$

In this case using the rational number enumeration $(r_n)$ leads to a bit of 'wheel spinning'.

Answer (score 5):

You have a bunch of questions, and probably the best way to clarify them is for you to read the book with in good faith and figure what he author is saying. But I will try to address your concerns.

Answer to Q.1. 
I do not think you need to say w.l.o.g. first, to choose the $V_{r_i}$. "W.l.o.g." is reserved for a different context, different types of proofs, e.g. given any infinite sequence of reals there is a theorem that it must contain either a non-decreasing or a non-increasing subsequence. You don't know which (unless you know more about the sequence), but you could always say: W.l.o.g let's us assume that the given sequence contains a non-decreasing sequence. That may help you prove something, e.g. if the original sequence was bounded, now you would have a bounded monotone, and hence convergent subsequence. So you could prove that every bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence, even if you can't tell whether it would have a non-decreasing sequence, but you may w.l.o.g. assume that, since the other option would be that is has a non-increasing sequence, and this case would be treated in a similar way. So, "w.l.o.g." is reserved for cases when you have two (or more) options, but they could all be treated simultaneously as if it was only one option, because they are similar.

I ended up stating and proving Theorem 2.7 below again, after overlooking the link provided by OP. 
(I just realized Theorem 2.7 is clickable in your question, but at any rate I wrote my version here and will keep it here, with notation that I like better, using $W$ for the open set that is "inserted" between a compact $C$ and open $U$. I prefer to denote the compact set in Theorem 2.7 by $C$, since $K$ is already used in the statement of Urysohn's Lemma).

Theorem 2.7. If $C$ is compact and $U$ is open with 
$C\subset U$ then there is an open $W$ with $C\subset W\subseteq\overline W\subset U$, and $\overline W$ compact.
Proof. For each $x\in C$ there is a neighborhood $U_x$ with $x\in U_x \subset\overline U_x\subset U$ and such that $\overline U_x$ is compact. Since $C$ is compact, there are finitely many $x_1,...,x_m\in C$ such that $C\subset(U_{x_1}\cup...\cup U_{x_m})$. We could let $W=(U_{x_1}\cup...\cup U_{x_m})$. Note that $\overline W=\overline{(U_{x_1}\cup...\cup U_{x_m})} = (\overline U_{x_1} \cup...\cup\overline U_{x_m})\subset U$, and $\overline W$ is compact, as the union of finitely many compact sets. Q.E.D.

In the present proof you use induction to conclude that the $V_{r_i}$ could be chosen in "such a manner". The author starts with choosing $V_0$ and $V_1$, or more precisely 
we apply Theorem 2.7 for the very first time to construct $V_0$ (using the compact $K$ and open $V$), such that $K\subset V_0\subset\overline V_0\subset V$, and $\overline V_0$ is compact. 
(That is, $C,U$ and $W$ from Theorem 2.7, as stated above, match $K,V$ and $V_0$ from the proof of Urysohn's Lemma.) Then we apply 2.7 to construct $V_1$ (using the compact $K$ and open $V_0$) such that $K\subset V_1\subset\overline V_1\subset V_0$, and $\overline V_1$ is compact. 
So far so good, since $r_1=0<1=r_2$ and $\overline V_1\subset V_0$. 
Then we apply 2.7 to construct $V_{r_3}$ (using the compact $\overline V_1$ and open $V_0$) such that $\overline V_1\subset V_{r_3}\subset\overline V_{r_3}\subset V_0$, and $\overline V_{r_3}$ is compact. In general, we apply 2.7 to construct $V_{r_{n+1}}$ (using the compact $\overline V_{r_j}$ and open $V_{r_i}$) such that $\overline V_{r_j}\subset V_{r_{n+1}}\subset\overline V_{r_{n+1}}\subset V_{r_i}$, and $\overline V_{r_{n+1}}$ is compact.

More precisely, if $n\ge2$ you would use all the sets $V_{r_k}$ with $k\le n$ (not just $V_{r_n}$) and following the author (and the induction hypothesis), 
there is a largest $r_i<r_{n+1}$ and a smallest $r_j>r_{n+1}$ (where $i,j$ are between $1$ and $n$), and (by construction so far) $\overline V_{r_j}\subset V_{r_i}$, and $\overline V_{r_j}$ is compact. We need to choose $V_{r_{n+1}}$ such that 
$\overline V_{r_j}\subset V_{r_{n+1}}\subset \overline V_{r_{n+1}}\subset V_{r_i}$, and 
$V_{r_{n+1}}$ is compact. 
Given (by induction hypothesis) that $\overline V_{r_j}\subset V_{r_i}$ and that 
$\overline V_{r_j}$ is compact,  we use Theorem 2.7 with $C=\overline V_{r_j}\subset V_{r_i}=U$ to find $W=V_{r_{n+1}}$ with 
$\overline V_{r_j}\subset V_{r_{n+1}}\subset \overline V_{r_{n+1}}\subset V_{r_i}$.

Answer to Q.2. So you know that the $\overline V_{r_k}$ are compact because you construct them this way, using Theorem 2.7. You use the induction hypothesis that the sets $V_{r_k}$ already constructed have compact closures, in particular $\overline V_{r_j}$ is compact, and then use Theorem 2.7 to construct (or pick) a new $V_{n+1}$ such that $\overline V_{n+1}$ is compact.

Ok, I see there is a potential source of confusion here. You wrote $V_j$, I assume you meant $V_{r_j}$. 
Just to make sure you realize that, let us assume (w.l.o.g. :) that $r_3=\frac12$. 
Here $n+1=3$, $r_j=r_2=1$, $r_i=r_1=0$. 
So then, once 
$V_1=V_{r_2}$ and $V_0=V_{r_1}$ are chosen with $\overline V_1\subset V_0$, then we pick $V_{r_3}=V_{\frac12}$ with 
$\overline V_1\subset V_{\frac12}\subset\overline V_{\frac12}\subset V_0$. You could write this alternatively as $\overline V_{r_2}\subset V_{r_3}\subset\overline V_{r_3}\subset V_{r_1}$, 
or also as $\overline V_{r_j}\subset V_{r_{n+1}}\subset \overline V_{r_{n+1}}\subset V_{r_i}$. 
But for most of the proof, the notation used would look more like $\overline V_1\subset V_{\frac12}\subset\overline V_{\frac12}\subset V_0$. 
So, if (w.l.o.g., just for an illustration) say $r_4=\frac56$ then we would have at the next step of the induction that $\overline V_{r_2}\subset V_{r_4}\subset\overline V_{r_4}\subset V_{r_3}$, that is $\overline V_1\subset V_{\frac56}\subset\overline V_{\frac56}\subset V_{\frac12}$. Note here that $n+1=4$, $r_j=r_2=1$, and $r_i=r_3={\frac12}$, and we could write the above as 
$\overline V_{r_j}\subset V_{r_{n+1}}\subset \overline V_{r_{n+1}}\subset V_{r_i}$. (You may want to figure the next step, if say $r_5=\frac13$, to practice with these indices.)

Answer to Q.3. It is enough to mention that $f$ is lower-semicontinuous and $g$ is upper-semicontinuous because the author goes on to show (further down in the proof) that $f=g$, hence $f$ is simultaneously lower-semicontinuous and upper-semicontinuous, and therefore continuous. (Exercise.)

Answer to Q.4. We assume $K$ is the one from the statement of Usysohn's Lemma. Your proof that $\{x:f(x)\neq 0\}\subset V_0$ (and the conclusion from there that 
$f$ has it's support in $\overline V_0$) is correct. The only minor quibble, your "quantifiers" are a bit unclear, I would suggest be more specific and explicitly say that "there exists" an $r$ with $x\in V_r$, and $f(x)\ge f_r(x)=r>0$. Where would that $r$ come from? Since $0<\frac{f(x)}2<f(x)$ there must be an $r$ with $\frac{f(x)}2\le f_r(x)$, whew too much writing, I got lost myself, will post this for now.

Edit addressing the comment below (but eventually I incorporated this edit in the answer above):
@AaronMartinez we apply 2.7 for the very first time to construct $V_0$ (using the compact $K$ and open $V$), such that $K\subset V_0\subset\overline V_0\subset V$, and $\overline V_0$ is compact. Then we apply 2.7 to construct $V_1$ (using the compact $K$ and open $V_0$) such that $K\subset V_1\subset\overline V_1\subset V_0$, and $\overline V_1$ is compact. Then we apply 2.7 to construct $V_{r_3}$ (using the compact $\overline V_1$ and open $V_0$) such that $\overline V_1\subset V_{r_3}\subset\overline V_{r_3}\subset V_0$, and $\overline V_{r_3}$ is compact. In general, we apply 2.7 to construct $V_{r_{n+1}}$ (using the compact $\overline V_{r_j}$ and open $V_{r_i}$) such that $\overline V_{r_j}\subset V_{r_{n+1}}\subset\overline V_{r_{n+1}}\subset V_{r_i}$, and $\overline V_{r_{n+1}}$ is compact.

Comment: Thank you for your help Mirko. First off I apologize for the $\overline V_j$ I meant $\overline V_{r_j}$ hehehe :) Then In the answer to Q.2. you say $\overline V_{r_k}$ are compat because I construct them this way, using Theorem 2.7 but I don't see it clear. Don't we apply for the very first time Theorem 2.7 to construct $V_{n+1}$ such that $\overline V_{n+1}$ is compact?

Comment: @AaronMartinez Thank you for asking, my clarification didn't fit in a comment, so I posted it above, at the end of my answer, as an edit. Please ask again if something is not clear, thank you

Comment: @AaronMartinez I am reading more carefully an earlier part of my answer, to see if it needs a revision, whether I got the $i$'s and $j$'s in the correct order, when I give a specific example with $V_{r_4}$. Will let you know if I make another edit.

Comment: Alright Mirko take your time ;) there is no need to hurry

Comment: @AaronMartinez good thing I tried to explain that proof so I understand it better myself :) I had to revise the details about $V_{\frac12}$ and $V_{\frac56}$ (that I used w.l.o.g. to illustrate the proof), since I had them wrong: I had assumed I knew what the author was doing, but your first comment to my answer made me take a look again and realize I was not reading the proof by the author carefully and correctly. I hope and believe I fixed it now. Let me know again if something doesn't make sense, this proof is trivial once one understands it, but only if all details are correct and precise

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen many authors (in particular in research papers, but in textbooks too) do not offer the luxury of a diagram. Thus, it becomes the responsibility of the reader to do their best to come up with a suitable diagram, which no doubt would be of a great help in Urysohn's Lemma. I wouldn't necessarily characterize Rudin's proof as index chasing (don't know what to say about my answer), in some proofs indices are important and unavoidable, and the reader has to take it carefully, one step at a time. The feeling of deciphering and understanding a proof is rewarding, this skill is valuable

Comment: @Mirko indeed, I agree with everything you said. I fear my wording came off too harsh (your answer is quite good - I did not mean to offend) so I will delete and redo my comment. I didn't mean there is anything wrong with this answer, merely that in this specific instance there is a very nice and fairly common diagram to have in mind that, in my opinion, makes this result far more intuitive and makes it easier to keep track of the ordering on rationals, and merely meant to suggest the OP try to find graphical intuition whenever possible (not always possible, e.g. with research papers)

Comment: May I ask what did you mean here _Where would that r come from? Since $0<\frac{f(x)}2<f(x)$ there must be an $r$ with $\frac{f(x)}2≤f_r(x)$_

Comment: @AaronMartinez We are using the definition of $\sup$ and $f(x)$ being defined as $\sup_r f_r(x)$. Since $f(x)>\frac{f(x)}2$, there must be an $r$ such that $f_r(x)>\frac{f(x)}2$. If there were no such $r$, then we would have $f_r(x)\le\frac{f(x)}2$ for all $r$ and therefore $f(x)=\sup_r f_r(x)\le\frac{f(x)}2<f(x)$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

The claim the author makes is that $x \in K$ implies $f(x)=1$ and this is indeed clear as you say. There is no claim that $f(x)=1$ implies $x \in K$.

It's just a matter of grammar: "$f(x)=1$, if $x \in K$" is just the same statement as $$x \in K \implies f(x)=1$$

Comment: I have updated my question, if you don't mind to take a look?