# How to prove $0\le f\le 1$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, proof-verification, proof-explanation

This is part of the [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3240789/explanation-of-specific-parts-of-urysohns-lemma-proof) of Urysohn lemma.

Part of it states

> It it clear that $0\le f(x)\le 1$ where $f=sup_rf_r$ and $f_r(x)=\begin{cases}r\qquad \text{if}\quad x\in V_r\\ 0\qquad a.o.c\end{cases}$

Please verify what I have done below to prove $0\le f\le1$

Case 1: consider $f_r=r.$ Then $f=\sup_rf_r=\sup_rr=r$. r is rational and it is defined on $[0,1]$ (definition stated at the start of the proof)
This implies $0\le f\le 1.$

Case 2: consider $f_r=0.$ Then $f=0$, clearly this cannot imply $0< f\le 1$.

then how should I proceed?

Please help

Comment: $sup_r $ is the function support or the supremum? It is not clear

Comment: @ArkPDEnational no it is the supremum. The author does not say explicitly but it is the most accurate notation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that $r$ is a rational in $[0,1]$ so that $$f_r(x)=\begin{cases} r &:\ x\in V_r\\ 0 &:\ \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ implies $0\leq f_r(x)\leq r\leq1$ for all $x\in X$. Note the upper and lower bounds are independent of $r$. Therefore, taking the supremum over all $r\in[0,1]\cap\mathbb Q$ gives $$0\leq\sup_{r\in[0,1]\cap\mathbb Q} f_r(x)\leq 1.$$Since $f(x)=\sup_r f_r(x)$, it follows that $0\leq f(x)\leq 1$ for all $x\in X$.

Comment: ooh elegant answer thank you!

Comment: I'm glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the fact that $f=sup_r f_r $ and, as you said, $r\in [0, 1] $, by definition of $f_r $, $0\leq sup_r f_r \leq 1$, what implies $0\leq f \leq 1$, finishing the proof.

Comment: what happened to the case when $f_r=0$ ?

Comment: Well, f will be zero only if $r=0$ in any other way it won't happen because the supremum will be positive. But even in the case when $f_r $ vanishes everywhere, its supremum will be zero, and then f will zero, so $0\leq f \leq 1$ once again.